# How to enable a disabled text field?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, onsubmit

I wanna know how do I enable a disabled form text field on submit. Also I wanna make sure if user goes back to form or click reset field will show again as disabled.

I tried to use

```
document.pizza.field07.disabled = false ;
```

It does disables the field, by clicking reset or hitting back button still keeps it enable.

Please guide.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To access this element in a more standard way, use [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) with [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute)

```
document.getElementById("field07").setAttribute("disabled", false);
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, it looks like field07 is a *name*, not an id.  As such, this should be what you want:

```
var allfield7s = document.getElementsByName("field07");
for (var i = 0; i < allfield7s.length; i++)
    allfield7s[i].setAttribute("disabled", false);
```

Comment: I tried 'this:document.getElementsByName("field07").setAttribute("disabled", false);' but its not working....  field07 is name...

Comment: Don't bother with buggy *setAttribute*, just set the property directly: `allfield7s[i].disabled = false;`

Comment: @Rob - I thought setAttribute was widely supported?

Comment: @AdamRackis: It is widely supported, but the property is simpler, just as standard, better supported and more readable.

Comment: @AdamRackis—it's widely supported, but implementations are inconsistent. Google "javascript setattribute issues IE".

Comment: Thanks @TimDown - didn't realize setAttribute wasn't perfectly supported

Comment: On my Browser Firefox setattribute didn't work. So I used @RobG 's solution.

Answer (score 11):

That is the only working solution for Me:

```
var allfield7s = document.getElementsByName("field07");
for (var i = 0; i < allfield7s.length; i++)
    allfield7s[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Setting disabled to false per the accepted answer will just change the attribute to 'disabled = false' and the element will remain disabled.

Answer (score 8):

You can enable a disabled html control with the following JavaScript code.

**document.getElementById('elementId').removeAttribute('disabled');**

Comment: Could you please add a link to the relevant documentation ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
$(function(){
    $("[name='field07']").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

We simply select all the elements where the `name` attribute is `field07` (using name because you said so in the comments of @AdamRackis's answer) and set its `disabled` property to `false`.

More about [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: While this works, I downvoted it because using a third party library to change the attribute value of an element is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable a disabled html control(like, input, textarea, button,...) with the help following code.

To disable:

```
document.getElementById("id_name").setAttribute("disabled", true);
```

To enable:

```
document.getElementById('id_name').removeAttribute('disabled');
```