# Enabling text box using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, css

I've following textbox which is initially ***disabled:***

```
<input id="txtCustFName" name="txtRCustFName" type="text" required disabled="true"/>
```

on click on following anchor tag i m calling the js to enable the above text box:
**HTML:**
    Enable

**JS:**

```
EnableTxt()
{
    document.getElementById("txtCustFName").disabled = false;
}
```

But this code is not working. I am not able to enable text box.

How can I do this?

Comment: The solution is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484181/how-to-enable-a-disabled-text-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable/disable using this:

```
function EnableTxt() {
       document.getElementById( '<%=txtRCustFName.ClientID%>' ).disabled = 'false';
   }
```

Comment: why is *false* between quotes?

Answer (score 2):

Removing the attribute worked allowed me edit the content of the textbox :

```
document.getElementById("questionnaireText").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

To set the textbox to `disabled` use :

```
document.getElementById("questionnaireText").setAttribute("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function EnableTxt() {
   $("#txtCustFName").prop("disabled", false);
}
```

Here "prop" is used for property/attribute of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
document.getElementById("txtCustFName").setAttribute("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by setting style using java script

for example:

```
document.getElementById("txtCustFName").setAttribute("style", "disabled:disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript

```
function myfunction(event) {
            alert('some anchor clicked');
            $('#txtCustFName').prop("disabled",false);
            return false;
      };
$(document).ready(function(){
          $('#myanchorid').click(myfunction);
          $('a.anchorclass').click(myfunction);
          $('#anchorlist > a').click(myfunction);
});
```

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<script type="text/javascript" id="Script1" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="myScript" src="myScript.js"></script>

<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <a id="myanchorid" href="#">Click Me</a><br />
    <a class="anchorclass" href="#">Click Me</a><br />
<input id="txtCustFName" name="txtRCustFName" type="text" required disabled="true"/><br />
    <div id="anchorlist">
          <a href="#">Click Me</a>
          <a href="#">Click Me</a>
          <a href="#">Click Me</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this....this will resolve your problem...

Answer (score -1):

You should use the attribute of the textbox.

jQuery:

```
($this.attr('disabled')) $this.removeAttr('disabled');
```

Please note that this is not supported in IE6

Comment: why using jQuery on a simple js question?